# Need to show hand cursor in Grid element

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have an ExtJS Grid, which has 5 columns.

In one of the columns, I am displaying an image using a `div` element dynamically from a renderer when clicking on some other button. I want to display a hand cursor when hovering over the image displayed by my renderer.

I tried adding inline style and `onmouseover` handler to display hand cursor. Hand cursor is coming when the very first time I load the grid and the `onmouseover` handler is also getting called. But when I load another set of data in the same grid, the hand cursor is not coming and the `onmouseover` handler is also not gettng called?

Could you help me get a hand cursor when hovering over the image which is rendered in a div tag in the grid cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your element a class like `<div class="myclass">` or `<td class="myclass">`. Also in your CSS, add;

```
.myclass{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Finally, if you want hand over all images, simply add the following line into your style;

```
img{
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: this is not helping. i don't have td. I have div. applied the class as said above not helping.:(

Comment: where did u applied the class? try my second option or try myRenderer: function(val){ 
var imgEmail= './resources/images/email.png'; 
return '<div align="center">'+val+'</div><div align="center"><img class="myclass" src="' + imgEmail + '" ></div>'; 
}

Comment: Hi...I am managed to make it work..actually code has been replicated in my project..so i had to do this 2 places..It's working .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by applying CSS like

```
.imgStyleHand {cursor:pointer}
```

or by style like

```
<img style="cursor:pointer" src="" alt="" />
```